# Adding a number to a MySql value with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following PHP to add 1 to the table value in my MySql database and update the database every time the code is executed.

```
function create_update() {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $numberofupdates = number_of_updates(); //'number_of_updates()' gets an INT from the database
    settype($numberofupdates, "integer"); //set the number to an INT if it already is not
    $spare_update_id = $numberofupdates + 1; //get number and add 1
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET updates=$spare_update_id WHERE id = $user_id"); //update the value to the database
}
```

The code works fine and updates to the database but it seems to update the value to 1 every time. If I were to manually set the database value to 4 and run the code, it will set the value back to 1 when it should be 5.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Var_dump($numberofupdates) please

Comment: `update members set updates =updates + 1 where...`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you need only 1 mysql query for this

```
function create_update() {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET updates = (updates + 1) WHERE id = $user_id");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend people to use concatenated queries. Instead they should use prepared statements. And in case if you do not know what those are, you can [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not running is because `$numberofupdates` is set to 0, so it's always evaluating as 0 + 1
This is happening because either `number_of_updates()` is returning zero or casting it as an integer is setting it to zero

Instead of all this fuss, you can simply run this query everytime to increase the number

```
UPDATE members SET updates = updates + 1 WHERE id = $user_id
```